# Parameter outside specified range using HGboost/Hyperopt library

Tags: xgboost, hyperparameter-tuning, bayesian

I am trying to use the HGboost library which uses the Hyperopt library for doing hyperparameter optimization of an XGboost model. The script runs fine but the optimized parameter for "n_estimators" is returning 52 which falls outside the minimum range specified in the hp.quniform argument (min set to 200). Could anyone guide me as to why this might be happening? I know that hp.choice returns the index but my understanding is that hp.quinifrom should not.

**Code extract**

```
# Initialize HGboost
hgb = hgboost(
    max_eval=500,
    threshold=0.5,
    cv=5,
    test_size=0.2,
    val_size=0.2,
    top_cv_evals=10,
    is_unbalance=True,
    random_state=None,
    n_jobs=-1,
    gpu=False,
    verbose=3,
)

# Define hyperparameter search space
xgb_reg_params = {
    'learning_rate': hp.uniform('learning_rate', 0.001, 1),
    'max_depth': hp.uniform('max_depth', 3, 30),
    'min_child_weight': hp.uniform('min_child_weight', 1, 10),
    'gamma': hp.quniform('gamma', 0, 0.5, 0.1),
    'reg_lambda': hp.uniform('reg_lambda', 0.1, 5.0),
    'subsample': hp.uniform('subsample', 0.5, 1),
    'n_estimators': hp.quniform('n_estimators', 200, 500, 5),
}

# Train and evaluate the model
results = hgb.xgboost_reg(X, y, eval_metric='mae')

# Access and interpret results
print("Best Parameters:", results['params'])
print("Model Summary:", results['summary'])
```